# How to efficiently check conditions inside a function?

Tags: function-construction

Consider a function as

```
f[n_]:=Module[{x,y}, 
x=Table[Sin[i],{i,0,Pi,Pi/(n-1)}];
y=Table[Cos[i],{i,0,Pi,Pi/(n-1)}];
Transpose[{x,y}]
]
```

Now, this function will work for all the values of `n>1`. However, for `n=1`, I want the function to return `{1,1}`. If I use `If-else` inside the function, I get the result, but, it gives me the error message as well.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: To be structurally consistent, `f[1]` should be `{{1,1}}`, i.e., a list of points. To be efficient, `f[1]={{1,1}}; f[n_Integer]:={Sin[#], Cos[#]}& /@ Range[0, Pi, Pi/(n-1)]`

Comment: What error? Share the code, which has the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f[n_] := Module[{x, y}, 
         If[n == 1, {1, 1}, 
            x = Table[Sin[i], {i, 0, Pi, Pi/(n - 1)}]; 
            y = Table[Cos[i], {i, 0, Pi, Pi/(n - 1)}]; 
                Transpose[{x, y}]]]

f[1]
(* {1,1} *)
```

Comment: Thanks. It's really a great way. Exactly the kind of solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

*Mathematica* is an expression rewriting language. Use that (and eliminate unnecessary code):

```
f[n_] := Transpose[{Table[Sin[i], {i, 0, Pi, Pi/(n - 1)}],
  Table[Cos[i], {i, 0, Pi, Pi/(n - 1)}]}]
f[1] = {1, 1};
```

When more than one rewrite is possible, *Mathematica* prefers the one with the more specific trigger, `f[1]` in this case

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[n_] := Transpose[{Table[Sin[i], {i, n /. {1 -> π / 2, _ :> 0}, π, π/(n - 1)}], 
   Table[Cos[i], {i, 0, π, π/(n - 1)}]}]

f[1]
```

> {{1, 1}}

```
f[3]
```

> {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}}

Answer (score 1):

This is more efficient.

```
f[1] = {1, 1};
f[n_?IntegerQ] /; n > 1 := Table[{Sin[i], Cos[i]}, {i, 0, Pi, Pi/(n - 1)}]

Table[f[i], {i, 5}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, 
>  {{0, 1}, {0, -1}}, 
>  {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}}, 
>  {{0, 1}, {Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2}, {Sqrt[3]/2, -(1/2)}, {0, -1}}, 
>  {{0, 1}, {1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}, {1, 0}, {1/Sqrt[2], -(1/Sqrt[2])}, {0, -1}}}
> ```